# Importing XML feed returns only the first value

Tags: 7, feeds

I am trying to import xml feed to custom content type and one of my XPath queries has multiple values being returned but only the first one gets posted to the node.

[image: xml struture]

the XPath query follows:

itinerary/itinerary/item/item/description/node()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3NPB.png)

Any ideas why only the first items gets posted? I've tried to run this query in XPath checkers and brings back the values fine. Also if I turn on the debugger on parser it brings back values as well. They just don't get posted on the node.

Thanks,
Dom